# Why this method gives an asymptote while being like nonsense, is this a coincidence or some logic below is not discovered.

Tags: calculus

I'm asked to find the asymptote of the equation: $x^3+y^3=4xy$.
Then I try to solve this simultaneous equation:
$x^3+y^3=4xy$, $y=ax+b$. Then after some expansion, the result turns out to be $(1+a^3)x^3+(3a^2b-4a)x^2+(3ab^2-4b)x+b^3=0$. In the beginning, I'm thinking of as x goes to infinity or negative infinity, the result should tend to zero, and equating all coefficients to zero, I computed them and got the equation for the asymptote ($a=-1$ and $b=-4/3$, but LHS is not zero). But soon I realize this is totally nonsense. What makes this method give the right answer and what should I use to find the asymptote in this case?

Comment: I suspect your method is related to one you can find in older texts, such as [**A Treatise on the Differential Calculus**](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseondiff05todhgoog/page/n303/mode/2up) by Isaac Todhunter (1864; see Chapter XIX) *AND* [**An Elementary Treatise on the Differential Calculus**](https://archive.org/details/cu31924001130354/page/182/mode/2up) by Joseph Edwards (1892; see Chapter VIII) *AND* [**An Elementary Treatise on the Differential Calculus**](https://archive.org/details/anelementarytre19willgoog/page/240/mode/2up) by Benjamin Williamson (1899; see Chapter XIII).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check the books and try to understand. Thank you :)

Comment: @Abel Wong and Alex27: Also of possible use are Jovan D. Kečkić, [*A method for obtaining asymptotes of some curves*](http://www.teaching.math.rs/vol/tm314.pdf), **The Teaching of Mathematics** (Mathematical Society of Serbia) 3 #1 (2000), 53-59 *AND* Haghdad S. Memauri and Herman Lee Windham, [*On asymptotes of the graphs of algebraic functions*](https://www.kappamuepsilon.org/Pentagon/Vol_52_Num_2_Spring_1993.pdf), **The Pentagon** 52 #2 (Spring 1993), 39-50.

Comment: Thank you! I checked the "A method for obtaining asymptotes of some curves" and the content really helps me a lot. Thank you for your warm help!

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard about your method. Maybe set the highest order coefficient to $0$ have some meaning. i.e. $1+a^3=0$. Set the other coefficient to $0$ probably is not correct.

Usually, if you can write down $y=f(x)$, then a standard method to find the asymptote $y=ax+b$ is to find the limits:

$a=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{y}{x}$,

$a=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} (y-ax)$ ,

$a=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{y}{x}$,

$a=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} (y-ax)$.

If they exist, you can find the asymptote.

For your equation, it is not easy to write down $y=f(x)$, but you can still take limit $x\rightarrow \infty$, and ignore the term $4xy$ as x tends to infinity and conclude $y=-x$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$. ( If $|y|>=c|x|^2$, I cannot ignore the terms $4xy$. In that case, those terms with $x$ can be ignored, and left $y^3=0$ which is contradict to the assumption.)

Thus, the asymptote is $y=-x$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, I checked the curve using desmos but I think y=-x doesn't seem like the asymptote.